# Hide rich:datascroller when page is 1

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, richfaces, datascroller

I have **same method for search and pagination**. where when we have list of record for 8 pages. Suppose if you make change in search crieteria and after that if you select new page number 6, then a4j:support will be invoke and update page number and records too, Here I have created an code at backend that If record size is 0 and total != 0 then we will search again with page number= 1 and new page list. But suppose the new record have only 1 page record, In that scenario I need to hide the rich data scroller. But I cannot come with any idea. Please help me out.

in datascroller i have set parameter as : rendered="#{students.totalPages > 1}", So while pagination if new record having single page then, datascroller is not being update because of the above condition and I need to hide datascroller next,prev,first,last buttons on a4j:support actionlistener=#{Students.search} and event="onchange". Please help me out.

Comment: You have described your source code in detail but it's better to add it to the question, providing a [mcve] in order to enable others reproducing what you try to do and what might be wrong.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to say. What is the real issue that once the datascroller is rendered, I need to hide it on a4j:support onChange event, If you have any example then please let me know.